# Estimated car insurance cost without personal information

Tags: united-states, car, insurance, car-insurance

What are the best websites for estimating car insurance price without leaving personal information?

Comment: note: even if this was on topic it is likely impossible to answer. A significant portion of the quote depends on the drivers record, and even on their credit score.  how each company handles the same driving record would impact the quote too much.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I think OP means "personal *identifying* information". The website could ask you all the required factors to build the quote, such as your credit score range, age, zip code, and driving record, and then not request identifying information such as email or phone unless you decide to move forward with one of the quotes. I'm guessing most websites don't offer this though because 99% of searches wouldn't turn into sales and the contact info becomes the only thing of value to them.

Comment: @TTT you're right. Additionally, imagine you're comparing full cost to own across 5-6 cars. It's physically impossible to call each insurance company and get that information.

Comment: ranges aren't good enough. My son has a good score but I thin file and one company specifically mentioned that  the thin file caused them to quote a higher rate.

Comment: There exists a profession, "insurance broker", separate from a single-company agent, that has been endangered by the internet, but will intermediate between you and the numerous insurance companies.

Answer (score 1):

Your car insurance - for a standard car like a Camry - can be somewhere between 300 and 4000 $ a year, depending on your age, location, family situation, home ownership, credit score, the insurance you pick, some other stuff, and especially *driving record*.
This is a pretty uselessly large range, but any further detail can only be given by that personal information that you don’t want to give.

Of course, they don’t only use your personal info to make the calculation, but also to spam you with offers for the next thousand years. It is difficult to avoid the latter, but you can try with fake phone numbers (anything with -555- in the middle), and fake or one-time email addresses. But you need to use at least the right ZIP code (pick a street around the corner, for example), and you probably need to use your real driver’s license number, to get any useful result.

Comment: I can enter all this information manually, including credit score and driving record, but I totally don't want to give away my SSN or phone number.